# JBPM Transaction timeout - completed with multiple threads in progress

Tags: spring, jbpm, redhat-bpm

While I am trying to start a process using KIE Server Client API I am getting this error.

What am I doing: I need to start few processes based on user selection. When I receive user selection, in a parent process WorkitemHandler I take the process ids and start them using KIE Server Client API. So, the parent process has to live until all the processes it started are completed. This worked fine on my laptop with windows 10.

I am facing the issue when I moved the JBPM and business processes code to Windows Server 2019 to AWS EC2.

When the client API tries to start a process, I see below error. I am using JBPM 7.31 single zip distribution.

> Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper check WARN:
> ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
> 0:ffffac1f2b9d:e1d5:6167e10d:c0 in state  RUN Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren WARN:
> ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac1f2b9d:e1d5:6167e10d:c0
> invoked while multiple threads active within it. Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05
> AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren WARN:
> ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac1f2b9d:e1d5:6167e10d:c0 completed with
> multiple threads - thread http-nio-0.0.0.0-8090-exec-9 was in progress
> with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
> java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
> org.kie.server.common.rest.KieServerHttpRequest.responseCode(KieServerHttpRequest.java:1329)
> org.kie.server.common.rest.KieServerHttpRequest.post(KieServerHttpRequest.java:719)
> org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl$6.doOperation(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:307)
> org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.invoke(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:809)
> org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:304)
> org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:299)
> org.kie.server.client.impl.ProcessServicesClientImpl.startProcess(ProcessServicesClientImpl.java:262)
> com.digitalgalaxy.service.util.JbpmClient.startProcessById(JbpmClient.java:172)
> com.digitalgalaxy.service.util.JbpmClient.startByProcessId(JbpmClient.java:88)
>
> Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction check WARN:
> ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action
> 0:ffffac1f2b9d:e1d5:6167e10d:c0 aborting with 1 threads active! Oct
> 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl
> afterCompletion WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by
> a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the
> original thread can handle it. [status=4] Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl
> afterCompletion WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by
> a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the
> original thread can handle it. [status=4] Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl
> afterCompletion WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by
> a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the
> original thread can handle it. [status=4] Oct 14, 2021 7:54:05 AM
> com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper doCancellations
> WARN: ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker
> Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX
> 0:ffffac1f2b9d:e1d5:6167e10d:c0 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8090-exec-9] WARN
> org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner - Could not commit session
> org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException:
> [create-component-kjar.create_project_process:2 - Create Project:1] --
> No available endpoints found
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.processWorkItemHandler(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:175)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:146)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:383)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352)
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.triggerCompleted(JoinInstance.java:272)

How can resolve this? What is the alternate approach?

Edit: The request landed into create-project process's workitem handler:

```
    beforeVariableChanged ==>[ProcessVariableChanged(id=initiator; instanceId=initiator; oldValue=null; newValue=wbadmin; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeVariableChanged ==>[ProcessVariableChanged(id=initiator; instanceId=initiator; oldValue=null; newValue=wbadmin; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    afterVariableChanged ==>[ProcessVariableChanged(id=initiator; instanceId=initiator; oldValue=null; newValue=wbadmin; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    afterVariableChanged ==>[ProcessVariableChanged(id=initiator; instanceId=initiator; oldValue=null; newValue=wbadmin; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeProcessStarted ==>[ProcessStarted(name=create_project_process; id=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeProcessStarted ==>[ProcessStarted(name=create_project_process; id=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=8; id=0; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=8; id=0; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=8; id=0; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=8; id=0; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=4; id=1; nodeName=Pre-processor; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=4; id=1; nodeName=Pre-processor; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    dummy preprocessor for time-being
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=4; id=1; nodeName=Pre-processor; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=4; id=1; nodeName=Pre-processor; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=6; id=2; nodeName=generate schema?; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=6; id=2; nodeName=generate schema?; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=6; id=2; nodeName=generate schema?; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=6; id=2; nodeName=generate schema?; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=5; id=3; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=5; id=3; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=5; id=3; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeLeft ==>[ProcessNodeLeft(nodeId=5; id=3; nodeName=null; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=1; id=4; nodeName=Create Project; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    beforeNodeTriggered ==>[ProcessNodeTriggered(nodeId=1; id=4; nodeName=Create Project; processName=create_project_process; processId=create-component-kjar.create_project_process)]
    Create Project WI On Entry Action
    .....STARTING FOR COMPONENT: create-component-kjar.create-odata-service
    comp id: create-component-kjar.create-odata-service, comp dependencies: null
    flattened processArgs: {inputJSON={comp_uuid=null, create_seq_id=0, other_attributes=removed_to_shorten_log}}
    Before startingt he process: create-component-kjar.create-odata-service with args: {inputJSON={comp_uuid=null, create_seq_id=0, other_attributes=removed_to_shorten_log}} containerId: create-component-kjar_1.4-SNAPSHOT
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper check
WARN: ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac1f2b9d:d093:6167d9db:d0 in state  RUN
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren
WARN: ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac1f2b9d:d093:6167d9db:d0 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren
WARN: ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac1f2b9d:d093:6167d9db:d0 completed with multiple threads - thread http-nio-0.0.0.0-8090-exec-2 was in progress with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
org.kie.server.common.rest.KieServerHttpRequest.responseCode(KieServerHttpRequest.java:1329)
org.kie.server.common.rest.KieServerHttpRequest.post(KieServerHttpRequest.java:719)
org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl$6.doOperation(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:307)
org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.invoke(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:809)
org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:304)
org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:299)
org.kie.server.client.impl.ProcessServicesClientImpl.startProcess(ProcessServicesClientImpl.java:262)
com.digitalgalaxy.service.util.JbpmClient.startProcessById(JbpmClient.java:172)
com.digitalgalaxy.service.util.JbpmClient.startByProcessId(JbpmClient.java:88)
com.digitalgalaxy.service.workitemhandlers.CreateProject.executeProcess(CreateProject.java:221)
com.digitalgalaxy.service.workitemhandlers.CreateProject.runProcessComponent(CreateProject.java:173)
com.digitalgalaxy.service.workitemhandlers.CreateProject.executeWorkItem(CreateProject.java:73)
org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:69)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.lambda$internalTrigger$0(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:146)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance$$Lambda$612/1378089277.run(Unknown Source)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.processWorkItemHandler(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:160)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:146)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:383)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.triggerCompleted(JoinInstance.java:272)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.internalTrigger(JoinInstance.java:62)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:383)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:417)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.executeStrategy(SplitInstance.java:116)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.internalTrigger(SplitInstance.java:62)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:383)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(ActionNodeInstance.java:60)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.internalTrigger(ActionNodeInstance.java:56)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:383)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:72)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:43)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:38)
org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:233)
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:498)
org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:212)
org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:195)
org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:187)
org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1873)
org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:122)
org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:40)
org.drools.core.fluent.impl.PseudoClockRunner.executeBatch(PseudoClockRunner.java:102)
org.drools.core.fluent.impl.PseudoClockRunner.executeBatches(PseudoClockRunner.java:69)
org.drools.core.fluent.impl.PseudoClockRunner.execute(PseudoClockRunner.java:61)
org.drools.core.fluent.impl.PseudoClockRunner.execute(PseudoClockRunner.java:39)
org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:597)
org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:563)
org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.internalExecute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:102)
org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:83)
org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:44)
org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:73)
org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:45)
org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.internalExecute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:66)
org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:52)
org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:29)
org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:398)
org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:66)
org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:37)
org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:41)
org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:264)
org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.startProcess(ProcessServiceImpl.java:115)
org.kie.server.services.jbpm.ProcessServiceBase.startProcess(ProcessServiceBase.java:95)
org.kie.server.remote.rest.jbpm.ProcessResource.startProcess(ProcessResource.java:174)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
----removed few lines----
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction check
WARN: ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffac1f2b9d:d093:6167d9db:d0 aborting with 1 threads active!
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl afterCompletion
WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl afterCompletion
WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl afterCompletion
WARN: HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
Oct 14, 2021 7:41:07 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper doCancellations
WARN: ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffffac1f2b9d:d093:6167d9db:d0
[http-nio-0.0.0.0-8090-exec-2] WARN org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner - Could not commit session
org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException: [create-component-kjar.create_project_process:2 - Create Project:1] -- No available endpoints found
        at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.processWorkItemHandler(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:175)
        at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:146)
        at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:197)
        at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:402)
```

Comment: Appreciate any help!

Comment: Do your WorkItemHandler throws an exception? It seems like it can't find an endpoint, this is relevant part: 

    WorkflowRuntimeException: [create-component-kjar.create_project_process:2 - Create Project:1] -- No available endpoints found at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.processWorkItemHandler(

Please show your jbpm workflow source. Probably you don't have endpoints in the WorkItemHandler?

Comment: Sorry to see this lately. It has found the endpoint and request landed into WorkItemHandler implementation. Within the implementation I invoke other processes. I am getting exception at this point. I think that error line is misleading. Adding log to question which indicates the invocation of WIHandler. Can you think of anything else? I can restart the bounty to reward your time!!

Comment: are you using rest workitem handler?